Powershell - keep only lines in txt files contain some selected words
I have a txt file and I would like to keep only a few lines in it
I want to a command that turns this
txt file:
;FFMETADATA1
title=TNT
disc=01
comment=
lyrics-eng=
\

\

\
album=Classic
genre=Older
artist=ACDC
encoder=Lavf59.17.102

Into this:
;FFMETADATA1
title=TNT
encoder=Lavf59.17.102

I used the command in this link:
Keep only lines in txt files that contain a certain word/character (Powershell) (Windows batch file)
PowerShell -Command "gci *.txt | foreach { (cat $_.FullName | ? { $_ -like '*;FFMETADATA1*' }) | set-content $_.FullName}"

But the txt file looked like this:
;FFMETADATA1
How to use the command to make the txt file have lines ;FFMETADATA1 title= and encoder= ?

Your command is basically correct, or let's say you're on the right path. But instead of -like you should use -match and a regex. 'METADATA|title|encoder' would return any line in your txt that matches any of the 3 strings. So the command would be:
If you want to create a new file:
cat .\su.txt | ? { $_ -match 'METADATA|title|encoder' } | set-content .\su2.txt

If you want to save it in the same file:
(cat .\su.txt | ? { $_ -match 'METADATA|title|encoder' }) | set-content .\su.txt

For all files in your directory:
gci *.txt | foreach { (cat $_.fullname | ? { $_ -match 'METADATA|title|encoder' }) | set-content $_.fullname  }

If we'd be code golfing, we could even make it shorter by dropping the ? (Where-Object) (and use sc for set-content - you shouldn't actually use aliases that much because it makes stuff harder to read but I'm now already code golfing i can't stop)
(cat .\su.txt) -match 'METADATA|title|encoder' | sc bla.txt

You can always adjust the regex, to be more specific. e.g: ';FFMETADATA1|title=TNT|encoder=Lavf59.17.102'
and if your regex gets to messy to read, let PowerShell create it for you
$Regex = @(
    ";FFMETADATA1",
    "title=TNT",
    "encoder=Lavf59.17.102"
) -join '|'

(cat .\su.txt) -match $Regex | set-content bla.txt

Edit:
As per OPs request - How to run this via cmd and with a hidden PS window:
PowerShell -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "gci *.txt | foreach { (cat $_.fullname | ? { $_ -match 'METADATA|title|encoder' }) | set-content $_.fullname  }"


If you're code golfing, use the alias sc for set-content. ;)

@CharlesBurge omg, i was too lazy to look for the alias :D. thanx!

@SimonS your commands were the most understandable for me... how do I execute them within my bat file and without the powershell console appearing on the screen?

@Clamarc I edited the question and added those infos.

@SimonS ok, I'll test it!

@SimonS it didn't work, when I run bat, the powershell command closes the cmd console and stops bat. Two observations, the command in my bat file is inside a For loop and inside SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

@Clamarc try to also add -ExecutionPolicy Bypass. if that doesn't work then you should open a new question, to ask specifically about that, since your original question is answered.

You can use the following script to get what you want. Either save it to a .ps1 file and execute it, or paste it directly in powershell and press enter.
Don't forget to edit the path.
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Temp\test" -Filter "*.txt"

$files | ForEach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content -path $_.FullName -Force
    
    $newfile = @()

    $matches = @(
        ";FFMETADATA1"
        "title="
        "encoder="
    )

    $content | ForEach-Object {
        $line = $_

        $matches | ForEach-Object {
            if( $line.StartsWith($_) ) 
            {
                $newfile += $line
            }
        }
    }

    rename-item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$($_.FullName).old"
    
    $newfile | Out-File $_.FullName
}


Sorry to be that guy, but don't you think this is waaaay to complicated for such a simple task? This almost looks scary :-). just use the original command in the question and -match instead of -like and that's it basically.

@SimonS I did that on purpose because that first example is really hard to understand and expand, whereas with my code, you can easily see what it does, and expand as needed. But feel free to post an answer of your own if you can do it clearly and simply with one line. That's what a Q and A site is for. :)

For that purpose, it's easier to use PowerShell than Batch.
- Quick Way
$Text    = ".\text.txt"
$toKeeps = ';FFMETADATA1', 'title=TNT', 'encoder=Lavf59.17.102'
$Null > $Text
$toKeeps | % {$_} >> $Text

- Without Backup
$Text    = ".\text.txt"
$toKeeps = ';FFMETADATA1', 'title=TNT', 'encoder=Lavf59.17.102'
$NewText = cat $Text | ? {$_ -in $toKeeps}
$Null > $Text
$NewText | % {$_} >> $Text

- With Backup
$Text   = ".\text.txt"
$Backup = "$($Text).bak"
if ( !(Test-path $Text) )   {'File not found'; pause; exit 0}
if ( !(Test-path $Backup) ) {Copy-Item $Text $Backup}
$toKeeps = @(";FFMETADATA1"; "title=TNT"; "encoder=Lavf59.17.102")
$NewText = Get-Content $Text | Where {$_ -in $toKeeps}
$Null > $Text
$NewText | ForEach {$_} >> $Text

output of them:
;FFMETADATA1
title=TNT
encoder=Lavf59.17.102


This is not gonna work. They want title=* and encoder=* to keep that line. And by rewriting your code so it works, it will essentially become the answer I already posted.

I have tested. only give another methods. Thanks.
